# Sorting Scores Java

Tags: java

I have a few methods that I was given from here a few days ago to help me with my scores. Basically when the game ends I want to get the top players with the best scores and put them into round 2, so if there were 8 players I want it to split them in half and the top half being the ones with the best scores, the methods below work fine but if there were 3 players in the game it would only take the top one instead of 2, 5 players in the game it would only take the top 2 instead of 3.

How do I get the top half with the highest scores and if say 2 players have the same score, then both of them would go through. For example:

```
Player 1 = 1;
Player 2 = 10;
Player 3 = 10;
Player 4 = 25;
```

Methods below would return player 4 and 3 but player 2 also has 10 points so he should be in it too.

```
public static Map<String, Integer> getTopHalf(Map<String, Integer> map){
    Map<String, Integer> sorted = sortByComparator(map);
    Map<String, Integer> out = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    Iterator<Entry<String,Integer>> it = sorted.entrySet().iterator();
    for(int i = 0;  i<map.size()/2; i++){
        Entry<String, Integer> e = it.next();
        out.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
    }
    return out;
}

private static Map<String, Integer> sortByComparator(Map<String, Integer> unsortMap){
    List<Entry<String, Integer>> list = new LinkedList<Entry<String, Integer>>(unsortMap.entrySet());
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Entry<String, Integer>>(){
        public int compare(Entry<String, Integer> o1,
            Entry<String, Integer> o2){
            return o2.getValue().compareTo(o1.getValue());

        }
    });
    Map<String, Integer> sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
    for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : list){
        sortedMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
    return sortedMap;
}

public static void printMap(Map<String, Integer> map){
    for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()){
        System.out.println("Key : " + entry.getKey() + " Value : "+ entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

And for testing I use this:

```
Map<String, Integer> unsortMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    unsortMap.put("B", 89);
    unsortMap.put("A", 45);
    unsortMap.put("f", 43);
    unsortMap.put("j", 47);
    unsortMap.put("h", 41);
System.out.println("After sorting descindeng order and deleting half......");
    Map<String, Integer> half = getTopHalf(unsortMap);
    printMap(half);
```

Comment: try adding a `+1` after `i<map.size()/2`

Comment: This is not a question, if you have a problem, you neglected to state it entirely. 
Please read ["How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: try for(int i = 0;  i<(map.size()/2)+1; i++)

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Integer> achievedPoints = new ArrayList<>(allPlayers.values());
Collections.sort(achievedPoints); /*- from few points to many points */
int requiredScore = achievedPoints.get(achievedPoints.size());

Map<String, Integer> playersInNextRound = new HashMap<>();
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> player : allPlayers.entrySet()) {
  if (player.getValue() >= requiredScore) {
    playersInNextRound.put(player.getKey(), player.getValue());
  }
}
```

Comment: How would i include players in the top half if they have the same score as someone who is in the top half? foe example, A and B went through because they were the top 2 highest scores from 4 total players, but C also has same score as B so he should be included too.